# Dynamically load component into dynamic position

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-smart-table, angular-dynamic-components

**UPDATED** (As I understood the issue better):

I would like to show a component depending on where the user clicks (which table row), I'm using ng2-smart-table, now the problem is there is no selector to where I need to load the component dynamically.
In my case its the button parent which is the row.

Each row has an open button

```
onOpen(event) {
 var selectedRow = event.target.closest(".ng2-smart-row");
 const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
    newRow.innerHTML = `
    <div #here></div>
  `;
selectedRow.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newRow.innerHTML);
}
```

Now while the open works, the `ViewChild` can't seem to find it so does the `createCompoenent` and throughs this.here is undefined

```
@ViewChild('entry', {read: ViewContainerRef}) entry:ViewContainerRef;


const openerFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(OpenActivityComponent);
const component = this.here.createComponent(openerFactory);
```

I guess the question is, can I set the @ViewChild dynamically?

Comment: I got to work with the dynamically loaded component, however, it doesn't work if I inject ```<div #here></div>``` dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a long time. here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-row-components-for-smart-table)

it is not complete and some tweaking, but covers everything in this question. And here is the [main source](https://hackernoon.com/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6) of the answer